# Joining a table 3 times to itself so that it each subset of the table will be another table aligned side by side in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join a table that has a single spell but multiple episodes in such a way that each subset will be another table. this is to prevent multiple occurrences of spells. below is my code that requires joining together.

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    *
FROM
    [HDM].[dbo].[FACT_IP_WARD_STAYS] ws
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         w1.DIM_SPELL_ID, MIN(w1.WSTAY_COUNT) firstw, 
         MAX(w1.WSTAY_COUNT) endw, MAX(w1.WSTAY_COUNT) - 1 pen
     FROM 
         [HDM].[dbo].[FACT_IP_WARD_STAYS] w1
     GROUP BY
         w1.DIM_SPELL_ID) X ON ws.DIM_SPELL_ID = x.DIM_SPELL_ID
                            AND ws.WSTAY_COUNT = x.firstw

SELECT TOP 5  
    *
FROM
    [HDM].[dbo].[FACT_IP_WARD_STAYS] ws1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         w2.DIM_SPELL_ID, MIN(w2.WSTAY_COUNT) firstw, 
         MAX(w2.WSTAY_COUNT) endw, MAX(w2.WSTAY_COUNT) - 1 pen
     FROM 
         [HDM].[dbo].[FACT_IP_WARD_STAYS] w2
     GROUP BY 
         DIM_SPELL_ID) Y ON ws1.DIM_SPELL_ID = y.DIM_SPELL_ID
                         AND ws1.WSTAY_COUNT = y.pen
    
SELECT TOP 5 
    *
FROM
    [HDM].[dbo].[FACT_IP_WARD_STAYS] ws2
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         w3.DIM_SPELL_ID, MIN(w3.WSTAY_COUNT) firstw, 
         MAX(w3.WSTAY_COUNT) endw, MAX(w3.WSTAY_COUNT) - 1 pen
     FROM 
         [HDM].[dbo].[FACT_IP_WARD_STAYS] w3
     GROUP BY
         DIM_SPELL_ID) Z ON ws2.DIM_SPELL_ID = z.DIM_SPELL_ID
                         AND ws2.WSTAY_COUNT = z.endw
```

Comment: This would be so much more clear if you add some sample data and expected outcome

Comment: Use of TOP without an order by clause is generally a logic fault. Do not assume your queries return specific rows just because you think you see a pattern.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.